# Implement custom ImagePickController in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I achieve something like this?

[image]

Right now I am using the standard `UIImagePickerController` like below, but it is quite boring and not a great user-experience.

**Standard View:**

```
    // MARK: ImagePickerController
extension MainViewController: ImagePickerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // delegate function
    func showImagePickerControllerActionSheet() {
        // choose Alert Options
        let photoLibraryActionn = UIAlertAction(title: "Aus Album wählen", style: .default) { (action) in
            self.showImagePickerController(sourceType: .photoLibrary)
        }

        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Foto aufnehmen", style: .default) { (action) in
            self.showImagePickerController(sourceType: .camera)
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Zurück", style: .cancel, handler: nil)


        AlertService.showAlert(style: .actionSheet, title: "Wähle ein Bild aus", message: nil, actions: [photoLibraryActionn, cameraAction, cancelAction], completion: nil)
    }

    func showImagePickerController(sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
        imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType
        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            makeWishView.wishImageView.image = editedImage
            makeWishView.wishImageButton.titleLabel?.text = ""
        } else if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            makeWishView.wishImageButton.titleLabel?.text = ""
            makeWishView.wishImageView.image = originalImage
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I couldn't find anything on this, happy for every help!

Comment: This is a really broad question. Likely you want to use a collection view. I'd suggest searching for `swift custom photo gallery`.

Comment: @DonMag  oh :/ I thought there was maybe a way to customize the view itself but I guess you can not do that..

Comment: @DonMag do you know any library that does this for you maybe ?

Comment: I don't use any 3rd--party libraries. A quick search on google for `swift custom image picker` gets a lot of results... I would think you could either find one you like, or find one *close* to what you want and then modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: @DonMag I searched for it but couldn't actually get a single one that looks even *close*  to what I would like to achieve :( (picture)

Comment: This could be a good starting point (not mine - just found via quick searching): https://github.com/CLOXnu/ConvenientImagePicker